# Cannot access the file location where json data is saved in python

Tags: python, json, chatbot

```
 with open("/home/akash/akashenv/PyCharm/PycharmProjects/chatbot_tensorflow{}/RC_{}".format(timeframe.split('-')[0], timeframe)., buffering = 1000) as f:
        for row in f:
            print(row)
            row_counter += 1
            row = json.loads(row)
            parent_id = row['parent_id']
            body = format_data(row['body'])
            created_utc = row['created_utc']
            sub = row['sub']
```

the error showing is:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/akash/akashenv/PyCharm/PycharmProjects/chatbot_tensorflow/database.py", line 37, in  with open("/home/akash/akashenv/PyCharm/PycharmProjects/chatbot_tensorflow{}/RC_{}".format(timeframe.split('-')[0], timeframe), buffering = 1000) as f: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/akash/akashenv/PyCharm/PycharmProjects/chatbot_tensorflow0/RC_0-01' Process finished with exit code 1

I have set all the names in RC_0-01, RC_0-02 and so on, and i am trying to rain a chatbot using these data set. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot access"? Why can't you? Are you getting an error when you run this code? If so, what's the error? What have you done to debug this? The very first thing I would do is create the filename and store it in a variable before opening, and then examining the variable to see if it's what I think it is.

Comment: As a wild guess, are you running this chatbot as `nobody` or some other unprivileged user, instead of as `akash`? If so, you’d need to make the directory where the files are stored world-accessible.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akash/akashenv/PyCharm/PycharmProjects/chatbot_tensorflow/database.py", line 37, in <module>
    with open("/home/akash/akashenv/PyCharm/PycharmProjects/chatbot_tensorflow{}/RC_{}".format(timeframe.split('-')[0], timeframe), buffering = 1000) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/akash/akashenv/PyCharm/PycharmProjects/chatbot_tensorflow0/RC_0-01'

Process finished with exit code 1    this is the error occuring

Comment: Put that in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: "No such file or directory" is clear, double check the exact path and file name.

Comment: i have done that chck a couple of times

Answer (score 0):

`'/home/akash/akashenv/PyCharm/PycharmProjects/chatbot_tensorflow0/RC_0-01'` is the path of the file you're opening, but you haven't specified a filetype. Is the name of your file `RC_0-01`, or is it perhaps `RC_0-01.json`? Furthermore, you might want to use the full path of the file you're using to avoid ambiguity. To do this, you can run the following code inside your `chatbot_tensorflow0` directory:

```
    from os.path import abspath
    print(abspath('RC_0_01.json'))
```

Or, alternatively:

```
    from os.path import abspath
    filepath = abspath('RC_0_01.json')
    with open(filepath, buffering=1000) as f:
        # Write your code here
```

Comment: FIY its RC_0-01.json. and after applying the code the same problem is coming

Comment: Hmm, in that case try making sure you're in the correct directory. Open a Python IDE (such as IDLE) in your `chatbot_tensorflow0` directory and type out the following code:

        from os import listdir
        print(listdir())

Make sure the files you want are listed. If not, then you're either in the wrong directory or the file you want to use does not exist.

Edit: Stack Overflow doesn't like me writing code in comments, so do a line break between listdir and print. The code I wrote only takes up 2 lines.

Comment: yes i did the following and every file name came as output. now what can i do?

Comment: Since you're running your code in that directory, the following will suffice:

`with open('RC_0_01.json', buffering=1000) as f:`

This should work because the filename is already in the directory from which you're running your code.